# SAPBinding Hard-coded logon parameters not allowed when using a Destination Configuration in C#

Tags: wcf-client, sap-dotnet-connector

We're using `SAPBinding` with a WCF-Client, the first invocation returns OK, but the second returns "SAP Hard-coded logon parameters not allowed when using a Destination Configuration in C#". Any help? This is the code:

```
        string connectionUriTemplate = "sap://CLIENT={0};LANG=EN;@{1}/{2}/{3}?RfcSdkTrace=False&amp;AbapDebug=False";

        string connectionUri = string.Format(connectionUriTemplate, SAP_CLIENT, SAP_TYPE, SAP_SERVER, SAP_SYSTEM_NUMBER);

        SAPBinding sapBinding = new SAPBinding()
        {
            ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
            SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(SAP_TIMEOUT)
        };

        EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(connectionUri);

        RfcClient client = new RfcClient(sapBinding, address);
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = SAP_USER;
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = SAP_PASSWORD;
```

Comment: You don't indicate what `SAPBinding` is. It's not part of SAP .NET Connector (as far as I know).

Comment: @SandraRossi is Microsoft.Adapters.SAP.SAPBinding used by WCF-Clients to connect with SAP (BizTalk uses the same) and this relies on SAP .NET Connector.